# Please consider merging [facebook-chat] & [facebook-messages]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

If you have enough reputation, please suggest [facebook-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-chat) & [facebook-messages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messages) as synonymous.

That is (keep in mind those tags have no descriptions), unless the former means the pop up version of the messages, but I don't think you really go down to such a resolution, especially that there's no difference in the mobile app.

Comment: I have suggested [facebook-messages] as [facebook-chat] [synonym](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/facebook-chat/synonyms). Please merge it.